# How to set the color of a TextView within an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, list, colors, textview

I'm trying to set different text colors (TextView) which are shown in a ListView. This is the ListView:

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="#a0a0a0"/>
```

This is the TextView in the row.xml:

```
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowtext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40sp"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:textColor="#a0a0a0"
android:background="#000000"
android:lines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

And this is how the list is filled:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, lstItem);
setListAdapter(fileList);
```

This all works fine. But now, I want to give each file in that list its own color. Is that possible?

Comment: you need a custom adapter.

Comment: What @Blackbelt said. There are plenty of tutorials (Google: "Android Custom Listview"), and many answered questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter()
{
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = new TextView(ListHighlightTestActivity.this);
        convertView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        ((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    convertView.setBackgroundColor((position == curSelected) ? 
        Color.argb(0x80, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x40) : Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ((TextView)convertView).setText((String)getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}

public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return "item " + position;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return 20;
}
});
```